# Intersections of sets in topological space

Tags: general-topology

If $A$ and $B$ are closed and disjoint subsets of a Hausdorff topological space, with $a\in A$ and  $b\in B$, then because the complement of $B$ is open, there exists a neighbourhood $U_a$ containing $a$ disjoint from $B$, and similarly a neighbourhood $U_b$ containing $b$ disjoint from $A$. How do I prove that $U_a$ and $U_b$ can be shrunk so as to not intersect each other?

Comment: Didn't you say *Hausdorff*?

Comment: You're thinking about this too hard. If $a\ne b$, then by definition of Hausdorff space, there exist neighborhoods $U_a$ of $a$ and $U_b$ of $b$ with $U_a\cap U_b=\varnothing$.

Comment: Relax and have some $T_2$.